# How to select certain numbers to assign a new value and others still keep same

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, conditional, assignment

For an array TestA={15,12,5,8,6}, I want to change the value of number greater than 10 into 0, as TestB={0,0,5,8,6}. When using "Select" command, I will lose some numbers.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen `/;` (`Condition`) in the documentation with respect to replacement (`/.`)?

Comment: Oh, thank you, it's very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
TestA = {15, 12, 5, 8, 6} /. x_ /; x > 10 -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
Clip[{15, 12, 5, 8, 6}, {0, 10}, {0, 0}]
```

> {0, 0, 5, 8, 6}